# Google Play hosting issue

Tags: android, apk

I have written an app that is hosted on our private server. We release updates to our customers via a push notification. All this works fine.

We always intended to publish the app on Google Play Store eventually but one of our customers that is a council, has published the app on the store without asking us. I think he wanted control of updating the app and the benefits of Alpha/Beta testing. This is causing us problems as when i try to upload the apk from my developers console, Google is saying the package name already exists on the Play Store.

I understand that once an app has been published on the Store then it cannot be deleted. It can however be unpublished. The following things concern me.

1. If the other person unpublishes the app, will i be able to upload the app from my developers console?
2. Will what i want to do require the other person to delete his developers console account?
3. If the other person does delete his account will there still be a reference to the package name after this deletion of account, meaning i still can't upload my app.
4. Now that someone else has published my app first, will i have to re-name the package of my app to upload to the store?

Any advise is appreciated, thanks in advance

Matt.

Comment: Why don't you change the package name in your app?

Comment: an application can only be uploaded is its properly signed . In your case which is done only then its on the market now only a mutual understanding can help you.

Comment: i don't want to change the package name as eclipse does not offer a very good solution for this. When i attempt to rename it, the new package name is not reflected through the apk. I use MapView, Google Push notifications, and the ZXing scanner library. These may have references to the old package name. It may be a little messy changing the package name when i may not have to. thanks

Comment: @TerrilThomas so i need to re-name then?

Comment: on renaming the project the apk name will only change.but your package name remains the same.Try changing the package name from the manifest.